# Kali Linux 2 and VMware workstation 12

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, kali-linux

I'm having problem Installing and running Kali Linux 2 on VMware workstation 12. when I first try to boot the ISO file in order to install it on a VM it doesn't do anything and just shows a black screen but after changing some settings or deleting the virtual partition and creating another one I could manage to go through half of the installation process but in the middle I got an error and couldn't continue.

This problem is only with VMware workstation 12 because when it installs and runs perfectly on the same workstation but with compatibility settings set to workstation 11.

in both installations I chose Debian 8 x64. is there any workaround?

Comment: It sounds like you've already found a workaround.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having similar issues with my 6700 and Kali 2.0 and Ubuntu 15.04. It turns out to be a kernel issue as Ubuntu 14.04 installed fine. Ubuntu 15.10 was released today and it installs without issue.

I would imagine building the latest Kali with updated kernel will resolve your issue. On a debian-based distro, this should build the latest Kali according to [their instructions](https://www.kali.org/downloads/).

```
apt-get install git live-build cdebootstrap
git clone git://git.kali.org/live-build-config.git
cd live-build-config
./build.sh --distribution sana --verbose
```

Alternatively, install Debian 8 and then install [Kali manually](http://www.tecmint.com/install-kali-linux-tools-using-katoolin-on-ubuntu-debian/) since Debian 8 is using a Skylake compatible kernel (at least one that doesn't crash during install). This is what I did and can confirm it is working.